# cannot downgrade bundle version

Tags: windows, cmd, visual-studio-2015

I want to install Visual Studio 2015 but i get an error.

**Error:**
The product version that you are trying to set up is earlier than the version already installed on this computer.

I already read the log file.
I already read that i have to downgrade the bundle version.
Now to my question. How can i downgrade the bundle version? 
I tried it by using the regedit, but when i try to downgrade there is an error coming.

**Error:**
The bundle version cannot be processed.

Some ideas how i can avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already handled it,

open the bundle version as admin (even if you are logged in as admin) go on characteristics and downgrade the number.